# Return dynamic value of a variable name in google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm new in Google tag manager and JavaScript and I have a variable in my source code called `name` that has a unique value for each customer. How can I write a custom java script that return the value for this variable.

For example `var name = '123'`?

Should it be something like that ?

```
function () {
ret = name.value
return (ret); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, if it's useful for anyone.

We can add a custom JavaScript

```
function () {
if (name) return name; else return false;  
}
```

It was embarrassingly simple :)

Comment: You don't even need a custom Javascript. there is a "Javascript" variable type that returns a named variable as long as it is in the global namespace (or undefined if the variable does not exist).

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a dataLayer variable to do this.

```
<script>
var name = '123';
dataLayer = [];
dataLayer.push({'name':name});
</script>
```

then in GTM you create a new dataLayer variable and name it 'name'. You would then access it within the tag like this {{name}}.

REF Link: https://www.optimizesmart.com/google-tag-manager-data-layer-explained-like-never/

Comment: Hi @Jay thanks for the information. But it is not located in datalayer.